# HTTP works, but HTTPS doesn't work (using Cloudflare, Github Pages, and Namecheap)

Tags: dns, hosting, github-pages, cloudflare, namecheap

I want to host my portfolio for as little money as I can.

So I bought my domain off of **Namecheap**, I'm hosting my website on **GitHub pages**, and I'm using **Cloudflare** so as to get a free SSL certificate and have a HTTPS connection available on my website.

When I try http://sitemeer.com/#https://josipmuzic.com
It shows that it's only partially available

But when I try http://sitemeer.com/#http://josipmuzic.com
It shows that it is available everywhere

This came to my attention when I asked my friend from a different country to check my website. After a bit of digging, we confirmed that the reason why wasn't because he was using a VPN, but instead, because of the country he was in.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I could do?
I have been googling for a while now, but I'm not exactly sure what I should be googling for, I cant seem to find anyone else having this problem.

Error: You can see the error you get when you open the https page by either opening the page https://josipmuzic.com, but I'll also provide it here
Fastly error: unknown domain: josipmuzic.com. Please check that this domain has been added to a service
Details cache-vie6323-VIE

Note: You likely can't open the HTTP page either because through Cloudflare I made it so that it always redirects from HTTP to HTTPS

Comment: Fastly error: unknown domain: josipmuzic.com. Please check that this domain has been added to a service. ( In belgium)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the errror disappeared after I put `AAAA` records to the DNS management. According to [this](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#configuring-an-apex-domain) documentation, you should put these IP addresses:

```
2606:50c0:8000::153
2606:50c0:8001::153
2606:50c0:8002::153
2606:50c0:8003::153
```

each as `Value` to a separate row, your domain URL (e.g.: example.com) to `Name`, `AAAA` to `Type`.